# What is the format for an idl enum?

Tags: c++-winrt

In my idl I have tried-

```
    enum ButtonClicks { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday } ;
    typedef  enum  ButtonClicks { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
```

I receive - 
    MIDL2025    [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting an identifier near ";"
    MIDL2025    [msg]syntax error [context]: expecting the keyword "interface" or...

Comment: The format of an `enum` type definition in IDL is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#enums) (this is IDL 3.0). I'm not sure which design would warrant declaring an `enum` type consisting of weekdays, given that the type name is `ButtonClicks`. It's probably something that should live in your code logic instead, all the more since this is highly dependent on the user's locale.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the enum is contained within the RuntimeClass. Moving it outside of the RuntimeClass compiles OK

Answer (score 0):

```
enum ButtonClicks { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}; 
typedef  enum   { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday} ButtonClicks;
```

the top one should just work by itself, if you want to do it via typedef try the bottom one